# How to change know item is saved in SharedPrefrence and set the Icon to favorite in menu?

Tags: android

I am building a project i used sharedprefs to have favorites but on restart singlemovie activity menu shows non favorite icon but that item is stored in favorite, how to show favorites icon in menu bar if its present in favorites
list. Help me on this and thanks in advance

In my singleMovieActivity java:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   this.menu =  menu;
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.favorite_menu,menu);
   // what should i do here to get icon favorite if its in favorites????
   return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id=item.getItemId();
    if(id== R.id.favorites_button_unchecked){
    Toast.makeText(this,"UnChecked 
    clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new SharedPrefranceFavorites().addFavorite(this, movie);
    menu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
    }else if(id==R.id.favorites_button_checked){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Checked clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new SharedPrefranceFavorites().removeFavorite(this,movie);
    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
    menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
```

My Shared Prefrence class:

```
    public class SharedPrefranceFavorites {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME= "TRAILER_APP";
    public static final String FAVORITES="MOVIE_FAVORITE";

    public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<Movie> favorites){
        SharedPreferences settings;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        settings 
    =context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor=settings.edit();

        Gson gson =new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites= gson.toJson(favorites);
        editor.putString(FAVORITES,jsonFavorites);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addFavorite(Context context, Movie homeSecreenModel){
        List<Movie> favroties = getFavorites(context);
        if(favroties== null){
            favroties= new ArrayList<Movie>();

        }
        favroties.add(homeSecreenModel);
        saveFavorites(context,favroties);

    }

    public void removeFavorite(Context context, Movie homeSecreenModel){
        ArrayList<Movie> favroites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favroites!= null){
            favroites.remove(homeSecreenModel);
            saveFavorites(context,favroites);
        }enter code here

    }

    public ArrayList<Movie> getFavorites(Context context){
        SharedPreferences settings;
        List<Movie> favorites;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME 
         ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)){
            String jsonFavroies = settings.getString(FAVORITES,null);
            Movie[] favrotieItems =new Gson().fromJson(jsonFavroies, 
            Movie[].class);
            favorites = Arrays.asList(favrotieItems);
            favorites=new ArrayList<Movie>(favorites);
        }else {
            return null;
        }
        return (ArrayList<Movie>) favorites;
    }
}
```

My menu File:

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/favorites_button_unchecked"
        android:title="Switch!"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_not_favorite"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorites_button_checked"
        android:title="Switch!"`enter code here`
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a flag(boolean) in your movie model **isFavourite** and set this flag to true when you add movie in favourites and check if movie isFavourites() show on you favourite list
i hope this will solve your problem